# C static array pointer address

Tags: c, pointers

We have a code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* aa(int s){
    static int ad[2] = {0};
    ad[0] = s;
    printf("aa() -> %p\n", &ad);
    return ad;
}

int main(void) {
    int *k = aa(3);
    printf("main() -> %p\n", &k);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile, run..
output

```
aa() -> 0x80497d0
main() -> 0xbfbe3e0c
```

or i misunderstood or this code have problems.

we are returning the same address for static array `ad` why on output they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `main` you're printing the address of the `k` pointer variable, not the address of the array that it points to. If you do:

```
printf("main() => %p\n", k);
```

you'll get the same address as printed in `aa`.

Comment: ok, but technically in low-end 
address of `k` isn't the address of `ad`?
so they might be the same, or no?

Comment: Yes, it is. When you return the array as a value, it's automatically converted to the address of the first element, just like when you pass it as an argument to `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote printf "&k" which should just be "k". Hence you displayed the address of the variable k, and not of ad. :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* aa(int s){
    static int ad[2] = {0};
    ad[0] = s;
    printf("aa() -> %p\n", &ad);
    return ad;
}

int main(void) {
    int *k = aa(3);
    printf("main() -> %p\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&k` returns the address of `k` and not the address it is pointing to. So, what you are getting is the address of `k`. You should change your `printf()` to

```
printf("main() -> %p\n", k);
                        ^
                        No need for &
```